# Really annoying error in mysql code

Tags: php, mysql, function, fetch

I am currently getting the error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\core\functions\image.php on line 23

I have tried the mysql_error and it returned:

> Query is Empty

I have looked at the query and there seems to be nothing wrong with it, I don't understand what I have done wrong.

Here is the code:

```
function get_images($album_id) {
    $album_id = (int)$album_id;

    $images = array();

    $image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_id`, `timestamp`, `ext` FROM `images` WHERE `album_id`=$album_id AND `customers_custnum`=".$_SESSION["customers_custnum"]);
    while ($images_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_query)) {
        $images[] = array(
            'id' => $images_row["image_id"],
            'album' => $images_row["album_id"],
            'timestamp' => $images_row["timestamp"],
            'ext' => $images_row["ext"]
        );
    }
    return $images;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for looking.

Comment: you have error in your query, or not connected to database, try to echo query and execute it using phpMyAdmin

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [pdo](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) or [mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli).

Comment: I have found the problem at last. Turns out I am just an idiot and wrongly named the database column, I named it user_id instead of customers_custnum. <_>

Thank you all for your time, I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some error handling so that you can see both the error and the SQL you tried to execute, e.g. something like

```
$sql="SELECT `image_id`, `timestamp`, `ext` FROM `images` WHERE `album_id`=$album_id AND `customers_custnum`=".$_SESSION["customers_custnum"];


$image_query = mysql_query($sql);
if ($image_query){
  while ($images_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_query)) {
    $images[] = array(
        'id' => $images_row["image_id"],
        'album' => $images_row["album_id"],
        'timestamp' => $images_row["timestamp"],
        'ext' => $images_row["ext"]
    );
  }  
  return $images;
}
else
{
   $err=mysql_error();
   print "FAILED: $err while executing $sql";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should not be using `mysql_*` functions. See the big red box [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Secondly, it looks like you may be leaving yourself open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should be [escaping your queries](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Thirdly, you should always be error checking as you go along. As per the docs for [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

> Returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to the
>   fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.

So you should be doing something similar to:

```
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if(!$res) {
   die('Query error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Although, you may want to be a little less brutal than simply dying out.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I am relatively new to PHP and learning from old Youtube Videos, which would explain the old version of PHP.

Comment: It would definitely be worth checking the documentation on [php.net](http://php.net) before using any functions from the videos. tutsplus have also done a nice [tutorial on PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) - It may also be worth running through that

Answer (score 0):

there is something wrong with your query. that is why **mysql_query** is returning a **FALSE** instead of a resultset or **"resource"**.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong.
**The correct query is**:

```
$image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_id`, `album_id`, `timestamp`, `ext` FROM `images` WHERE `album_id`=$album_id AND  `customers_custnum`=".$_SESSION['customers_custnum']);
```

You were missing `album_id` from query string. `Edit` your query and your code will work `perfectly`.